# Error: int cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java, compiler-errors, int, dereference, primitive-types

I seem to be getting an "Error: int cannot be dereferenced" error when compiling. I've looked up reasons why this happens and despite that I'm not sure how I'm suppose to fix it.

```
public class NetID_BaseballPitcher
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    private final int maxgames = 20;
    private int[] gamesPitched = new int[maxgames];
    private int count, totalRuns;
    private float totalInnings;

    public int inputGameData()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            gamesPitched[i] = new NetID_BaseballGame();
            gamesPitched[i].inputGame();
        }
    }  
}
```

And here is Baseballgame.java

```
public class NetID_BaseballGame
{
    private static int runs;
    private static int gameNum;
    private static float innings;
    public static void inputGame()
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Game # ");
            gameNum = in.nextInt();
        } while( gameNum < 0 );
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Number Innings");
            innings = in.nextInt();
        } while( ( innings < 0 ) && ( innings > 10 ) );

        do
        {
            System.out.print("Number Runs");
            runs = in.nextInt();
        } while( runs < 0 );
    }
}
```

While compiling BaseballPitcher.java, I get this:

```
NetID_BaseballPitcher.java:45: error: incompatible types
            gamesPitched[i] = new NetID_BaseballGame();
                          ^
  required: int
  found:    NetID_BaseballGame
NetID_BaseballPitcher.java:46: error: int cannot be dereferenced
        gamesPitched[i].inputGame();
```

I'm assuming that I'm missing something completely obvious, and I'm just spinning where I'm at. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `gamesPitched` to be an array of `int` values, but that's not what you need. From the requirements, it looks like you should declare it like this:

```
private NetID_BaseballGame[] gamesPitched = new NetID_BaseballGame[MAX_GAMES];
```

You will also need to initialize your `count` variable somewhere.